# React native Error at usehooks in the fuction

Tags: reactjs

React Hook "useState" is called in function "login" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Clear the error

Comment: Sounds like you just need to rename your `login` component to "start with an uppercase letter" as per error message says. So the function should be `export function Login(props)` instead.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.